# Async function returns two different results after another

Tags: function, flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I have written an async Flutter/Dart function which behaves unexpectedly in my opinion. Following code structure:

```
static Future<bool> verifySometing() async {
   try {
      await getCloudData().then((snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.exists && snapshot.hasData) {
            bool dataValid = await validateData(snapshot.data);
            if (dataValid) {
               print('Data is correct');
               return true;
            }
         }
      });
   } catch (e) {
      print('Error $e');
      return false;
   }
   print('Something went wrong');
   return false;
}
```

The expected result would be that the function awaits the cloud data, then awaits validation and returns true if the data is valid. In this case, the console would show the following and the function would return true:

```
Data is correct
```

What happens in practice is that the console shows the following output and the function first returns true and then false:

```
Data is correct
Something went wrong
```

This goes against anything I thought to know about funtions in Dart because I always assumed that once return is fired, the function is done. Any ideas how this happens?

Comment: Keep in mind that when you use `await` you shouldn't need to use `then` and vice versa. Plus the `await` stops the execution of the code, while freeing up the thread for other work, and only continues when the awaited work is done. Differently from the `then`, which does not stop the execution of the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line.

```
await getCloudData().then((snapshot) {
```

Here, instead of just `await`ing, you have also attached a `then` callback. So in actuality, whatever you are returning is return value of the `callback` function ie., `(snapshot) {}`.

The callback function that you need to pass into the `then` takes that `return true` and gives it to us as the result of `await`.

So, if you would've put something like

```
var bool = await getCloudData().then((snapshot) { ..... });
```

Then this `bool`, would've been equal to `true`. That's it. No return from the your main function.

Change it to this,

```
var snapshot = await getCloudData();
if (snapshot.exists && snapshot.hasData) {
  bool dataValid = await validateData(snapshot.data);
  if (dataValid) {
    print('Data is correct');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Hope, I was able to explain clearly.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of faults in your assumptions.

First, you've attached a `then` to the future returned by `getCloudData()`. This means that you aren't awaiting `getCloudData()`, but instead the *additional* future returned by `getCloudData().then(...)`, and that future will return when the callback function passed to it completes. (And unless the first future throws an error, the callback *will* be called.)

Second, the callback function operates on its own scope. So this code is not doing what you think it's doing:

```dart
bool dataValid = await validateData(snapshot.data);
if (dataValid) {
  print('Data is correct');
  return true;
}
```

This return will affect the *callback* function, not the `verifySomething` function.

Given these, the order of operation is as follows:

1. The `validateSomething` function `await`s `getCloudData().then(...)`.
2. `getCloudData()` gets called.
3. `getCloudData()` returns, the callback passed to `then` is called.
4. (Assuming the snapshot has data) `validateData` is called.
5. (Assuming data is successfully validated) "Data is correct" gets printed and the callback function returns `true`.
6. `validateSomething` is notified that the awaited future is complete, so execution resumes.
7. "Something went wrong" gets printed and the `validateSomething` function returns `false`.

Generally speaking, these kinds of errors are common when mixing `async/await` and `then` patterns. Unless you know what you're doing, stick with either one or the other, preferably the `async/await` pattern. For example, a refactor of your code to eliminate the call to `then` is as follows:

```dart
static Future<bool> verifySometing() async {
   try {
      final snapshot = await getCloudData();
      if (snapshot.exists && snapshot.hasData) {
        bool dataValid = await validateData(snapshot.data);
        if (dataValid) {
          print('Data is correct');
          return true;
        }
      }
   } catch (e) {
      print('Error $e');
      return false;
   }
   print('Something went wrong');
   return false;
}
```

Now that there isn't a pesky closure to deal with, `return` will return from `validateSomething` as expected and you don't need to deal with issues like callbacks and scope.